# Are javax packages stable?

Tags: java, stability

Is it true that **javax** packages, in the Java language, are not stable and can be deprecated in future versions? In most of our project we use the swing packages which are included in **javax**.

Comment: You're probably thinking of the com.sun... packages.  Those are the ones that are internal and shouldn't be used.  As mentioned in the other answer, the javax packages are perfectly fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is nothing to worry about.  There are Java classes that have been deprecated for the last 15 years but they're still in the core libraries for backwards compatibility.

Even if a whole swathe of javax.* classes get deprecated, they won't disappear.

You might want to take a look at [Java 9's modular system](http://mreinhold.org/blog/jigsaw-modular-images) too.